# Get last item emited by a Flow and dont receive updates

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

What is the best way to obtain the last element emitted by a flow without receiving updates.

**Question:**
I use a flow to observe changes in certain shared preferences, but sometimes I want to know the current value of that preference. I always use two functions, one to observe the values in a flow and the other to capture the data directly, is there any way to archive the same behavior with just the observer function?

```
suspend fun getBreadcrumb(): Breadcrumb =
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) context@ {
            ...
        }

fun observeBreadcrumb(): Flow<Breadcrumb> {
        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Consider using [StateFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/)

`StateFlow` is a new API that was recently added to the coroutines standard library. You can consume it like a regular flow, but it also has a `value` property that gets the most recent value.

At the moment, the only way to send a new value to a state flow is to update its `value` property. You can't yet turn a regular flow into a state flow, though there is an [open proposal for it](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2047).

Let's say you send values to the flow like this:

```kotlin
val breadcrumbs = MutableStateFlow(someValue)

launch {
    while (isActive) {
        waitForSomeCondition()
        breadcrumbs.value = getLatestValue()
    }
}
```

You can retrieve the latest value whenever you want, for example like this:

```kotlin
launch {
    while (isActive) {
        delay(1000)
        println("Current value is ${breadcrumbs.value}")
    }
}
```

But you can also collect it like a regular flow, and receive the new value each time it changes:

```kotlin
launch {
    breadcrumbs.collect {
        println("Current value is ${it}")
    }
}
```

This is an [experimental](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/evolution/components-stability.html) API, so there are likely to be improvements and changes down the line.

Comment: Does `collect` actually stop the flow emitting?

Answer (score 2):

You could expose your Flow as a LiveData with Flow's `asLiveData` extension function:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel {
    ...
    val myFlowAsLiveData: LiveData<Breadcrumb> = myFlow.asLiveData()
    ...
}
```

Then you can observe it as usual and if you need its current value just use its `value` property:

```
myViewModel.myFlowAsLiveData.value
```

Comment: I tried this but it dont seems to work i alwsys return null

Comment: Does your livedata has any active observers? According to docs livedata created by builder receives value only then.

Answer (score 2):

`last()` or `lastOrNull()` should be used to achieve this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35051178)

Comment: @NigamPatro how is this not an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with coroutine function [mapLatest](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/map-latest.html)

```
val breadcrumbs = MutableStateFlow(someValue)

breadcrumbs.mapLatest { breadcrumb ->
  println("Latest value is ${breadcrumb}")
}
```